# Creating a new user account on Windows without "getting ready for you"

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-11, user-accounts, oobe

For Reasons™, I'm writing an installer for an app that (among other things) programmatically creates a new user account on the PC, that the (human) user can later use to interactively log in.  This much is fine.

However the first time they actually log in, it displays the "Hi" "We're getting ready for you" experience, which I'd like to be able to skip.

I know that particular display can be disabled via GPO, but that's not quite what I want -- I want to know how to do whatever that is doing in advance at the time that I'm creating the user, such that on first actual login it doesn't need to do anything more.  (As if the first login is actually the second.)

I'm currently using [`NetUserAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuseradd) to actually create the account, and even calling [`LogonUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw) and [`CreateProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createprofile) in the hope that this was most of what it was doing, but this seems insufficient.  What other steps are needed to do the user-OOBE in advance?

Comment: There's unlikely to be a way to skip it other than via GPO. Microsoft want to ram that stuff down users' throats as much as possible these days, in their never-ending quest to get people to use their web browser by default.